# How to process request based on url parameter?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a java webapplication in which I have client area is only for the client.

After logging in, the client would able get a type of client area where the client can perform various operations like edit, add , update , setting etc.

In the side menu bar, in anchor link I kept the URL like this: `href="clientarea.jsp?action=edit"` how do I process this request, because at the time of the user login I performed `doPost` method and after successfully logging in, the user was redirected to clientarea.jsp.

Now again user sending this request then where should I process this request in same `doPost` method or `doGet` method and according to `href=""` action parameter I want to change only square parts area dynamically which I've shown in different colors.

How should I proceed ?

Here's the image:
[image]

Some sample code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                      throws ServletException, IOException 
{   
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    RequestDispatcher rd = null;

    String email = request.getParameter("loginEmail");
    String password = request.getParameter("loginPassword");
    System.out.println("---login email id" + email + "Login password " + password);

    RegisterSalonDao loginObj = new RegisterSalonDAOImpl();
    bbbeans.RegisterUserBean regUserObject = loginObj.loginValidation(email, password);

    if (regUserObject != null) 
    {
        System.out.println("when data are returned throught reguserobject method =======");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("userLogin", regUserObject);

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/clientarea.jsp");
    } 
    else if (regUserObject == null) 
    {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
    } 
    else 
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/error.jsp");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no image..

Comment: It was edited out, back in now.

Comment: Hey @Frits i didn't get you ? can you explain how would i do that ..?

Comment: Your image was removed, I edited your question and put it back, that's all :)

Comment: @Frits Thanks alot